# Strange 3d Procedural generation output

Tags: java, random, 3d, procedural

So for the past several days, I have been working on making a procedural generation program written in java, however whenever I make the output, it comes out with a washed, paper like texture.  I don't understand *why* it's doing this, and while it's pretty cool, I was wondering if somebody could explain to me how my program is arriving at this result.

Source: http://pastebin.com/frCh03VW

I was expecting this logic to create a more cloud like heightmap, but instead it gave me this:

Large image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjKod.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Nicholas,

I apologize in advance if this is incorrect, but looking over your code and compiling it myself I have found the pattern is largely dependent on the mshift variable. If you set it to a relatively large number (for my purposes, I set it at 1000), you will find a lot more static and white noise. Conversely, if you set it relatively low (for my purposes, I set it at 10), you will get the ocean wave-like or washed paper description you gave.

I would assume, with out much testing, that the image created has a lot to do with the fact that you go through each x value before the corresponding y.

I don't have much more time to contribute to this, as I have my own project that is due at 11:59PM today, but perhaps a project I did a while back might help you. I made a paste in case you found benefit in it:

http://pastebin.com/c0umWA1N

Answer (score 0):

You are using `java.util.Random` to generate your texture. Nothing is really random in computers, of course. The standard Java library uses the classic [linear congruential pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), which is fast and good for most purposes, but is still considered weak for serious stuff. By "weak" I means it can be predictable and exhibits "non-randomness" when used intensively. This is possibly the source of the patterns that you see here.

Another possible source of problem is that you are first generating an array of random seeds. But if you look at the implementation of `Random.next()` in `java.util`:

```
protected int next(int bits) {
    long oldseed, nextseed;
    AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
    do {
        oldseed = seed.get();
        nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
    } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
    return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

you see that the process of Random is to generate a new seed and return a value based on a simple calculation on that seed. I don't have the mathematical background to be sure of that, but maybe this technique would produce a list of seeds that would produce similar pseudo-random sequences when you use them afterwards because they are dependent on each other in some way, having been produced by the same random generator, and would also generate patterns.

What you can try: use a better pseudo-random generator. You can use `java.security.SecureRandom`, which is "cryptographically strong", so it should be good enough for your usage. Unfortunately, it is not as fast as `java.util.Random`. But you can at least give it a try and see if you find the same patterns. If not, then the random generator was bad; if you still find patterns, then most probably it is coming from your algorithm.

If I am right to say that the pseudo-random generator is not random enough, and if `SecureRandom` is too slow for you, you can find online an implementation of the "Mersenne Twister" algorithm, which is fast and better than the linear congruential method.

Comment: I tried replacing my Randoms with Secure-randoms, but it didn't make any difference.  Which is strange, because I really thought that was going to work.  Thanks anyways, :)